# OpenAPI v3, how to hide objects in "Schemas" section

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm using OpenAPI v3 to create my API docs and having them hosted on [app.swaggerhub.com](https://app.swaggerhub.com)

Is there a way to hide an item from showing up in the `Schemas` section at the bottom? The real API has dozens of Schema objects, so it'd be very helpful to hide some of them.

Example:

Running this on https://editor-next.swagger.io/

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "Swagger Petstore - OpenAPI 3.0",
    "description": "example",
    "version": "1.0.11"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/pet": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Add a new pet to the store",
        "description": "Add a new pet to the store",
        "operationId": "addPet",
        "requestBody": {
          "description": "Create a new pet in the store",
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
              }
            },
            "application/xml": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
              }
            },
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
              }
            }
          },
          "required": true
        },
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful operation",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                }
              },
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Order": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": 10
          },
          "petId": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": 198772
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32",
            "example": 7
          },
          "shipDate": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Order Status",
            "example": "approved",
            "enum": [
              "placed",
              "approved",
              "delivered"
            ]
          },
          "complete": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "order"
        }
      },
      "Customer": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": 100000
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "fehguy"
          },
          "address": {
            "type": "array",
            "xml": {
              "name": "addresses",
              "wrapped": true
            },
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Address"
            }
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "customer"
        }
      },
      "Address": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "street": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "437 Lytton"
          },
          "city": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Palo Alto"
          },
          "state": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "CA"
          },
          "zip": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "94301"
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "address"
        }
      },
      "Category": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": 1
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "Dogs"
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "category"
        }
      },
      "User": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": 10
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "theUser"
          },
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "John"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "James"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "john@email.com"
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "12345"
          },
          "phone": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "12345"
          },
          "userStatus": {
            "type": "integer",
            "description": "User Status",
            "format": "int32",
            "example": 1
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "user"
        }
      },
      "Tag": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "tag"
        }
      },
      "Pet": {
        "required": [
          "name",
          "photoUrls"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "example": 10
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "doggie"
          },
          "category": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Category"
          },
          "photoUrls": {
            "type": "array",
            "xml": {
              "wrapped": true
            },
            "items": {
              "type": "string",
              "xml": {
                "name": "photoUrl"
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "array",
            "xml": {
              "wrapped": true
            },
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Tag"
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "pet status in the store",
            "enum": [
              "available",
              "pending",
              "sold"
            ]
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "pet"
        }
      },
      "ApiResponse": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "code": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "xml": {
          "name": "##default"
        }
      }
    },
    "requestBodies": {
      "Pet": {
        "description": "Pet object that needs to be added to the store",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
            }
          },
          "application/xml": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "UserArray": {
        "description": "List of user object",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/User"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "petstore_auth": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "flows": {
          "implicit": {
            "authorizationUrl": "https://petstore3.swagger.io/oauth/authorize",
            "scopes": {
              "write:pets": "modify pets in your account",
              "read:pets": "read your pets"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "api_key": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "api_key",
        "in": "header"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...this gets generated:

[image: generated API]

In this example, I'd like to hide a few of the schema items from view (like `Customer` or `Address`).

Note: I'm not self-hosting, so I'm hoping there's a tag I can put into the YAML or JSON.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

There's a parameter `defaultModelsExpandDepth`, should be set equals `-1`
According [swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/)

Api Platform YAML example:

```
api_platform:
  version: 3.0
  openapi:
    swagger_ui_extra_configuration:
      defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1
```